# editcap -A and -B: using timestamp with nanoseconds example

Tags: editcap

I'm trying to get editcap to use a timestamp with nanoseconds, but I am unable to do this.

sample timestamp: `2022-01-23 23:10:05.237000000Z`

```
TZ=UTC editcap -A '2022-01-23 23:10:05.237000000Z' -F nseclibpcap <some pcap file> <new trimmed pcap file>
```

This appears to only go the second rather than the nano second.

Does anyone have a sample cmd line on how they went about using nanoseconds?

Answer (score 0):

At least one of your command-line options to [`editcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) is incorrect.  If you run `editcap -F` as suggested in the man page, you'll see that **nseclibpcap** is not a valid output capture file format.  Try running the command again, but this time with a valid output capture file format specified, for example:

```
TZ=UTC editcap -A '2022-01-23 23:10:05.237000000Z' -F pcap infile.pcap outfile.pcap
```